# Retrieving image from encoded json data

Tags: json, vb.net, image

**This question is related to Visual Basic .NET 2010**

How do I recover the image from this encoded json string? What's it even encoded with?
I'm trying to screenshot a website using the Google PageSpeed API.

```
 "screenshot": {
  "data": "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",
  "height": 240,
  "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
  "width": 320
 }
```

Comment: It looks like base64 with `-` instead of `/` and `_` instead of `+`.

Comment: Can you post the url of the google API documentation for this part?

Answer (score 0):

Like minitech is saying, there seem to be weird characters. You can decode it like this.

```
    Dim decodedBytes() As Byte
    Dim encodedString As String = "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"

    encodedString = encodedString.Replace("-", "/")
    encodedString = encodedString.Replace("_", "+")

    decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString)
```